# TypeScript compiler (tsc) doesn't recognize import aliases

Tags: typescript, tsc, tsconfig

First and foremost, I have prepared [this sample GitHub repository](https://github.com/farzadmf/tsc-import-alias-issue) as a minimum thing to reproduce my issue.

I'm having a problem with `tsc` not being able to compile my TypeScript to JavaScript.

I'm using import aliases, and I'm able to directly run my application using [`ts-node`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/) and [`tsconfig-paths`](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths) like this:

```
ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register main
```

But, the confusing thing for me is that when I run the following:

```
tsc --outDir out main
```

I see `TS2307` errors from the compiler, complaining that it cannot find modules defined by my import aliases:

```
main.ts:1:24 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@utils/.'.

1 import * as utils from '@utils/.';
                     ~~~~~~~~~~

main.ts:2:22 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@cmd/.'.

2 import * as cmd from '@cmd/.';
                   ~~~~~~~~
```

What am I missing here? I thought that `tsc` should work fine without any "helper" (as `tsconfig-paths` is doing for `ts-node`)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass your tsconfig.json to `tsc`

`tsc --config path/to/tsconfig.json --outDir out main`

Comment: Thank you @hackape for your answer, but I don't think there's a `-c` option for `tsc`; I tried doing: `tsc -p path/to/tsconfig.json --outDir out`, but, I'm testing it on Windows, and it doesn't do anything (I will try at home with Linux later)

Comment: Sorry my fault it should be `--config`

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is with versions, try updating you `typescript` to `3.4.5+` and `tsconfig-paths` to the latest. Add an NPM script property to package.json, that way all the calls made `tsc -p tsconfig.json` will resolve to NPM packages and not to the global

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -v && tsc -p tsconfig.json",
    "prestart": "rimraf dist && npm run build",
    "start:project": "npm run prestart && node dist/main.js",
}
```

Then call the scripts by doing: **npm run start:project**